# Avoid pathname Composer vendor/autoload

Tags: php, composer-php

I used SSH to download composer and mailgun API Dependencies to my project. Now For sending an email I had all the code in a file `mail.php` that has `include('PATH to vendor/autoload.php')` and function `send($to, $subject, $body)`.

Now my problem is, when I try to include this file to send an email, `include(PATH to vendor/autoload)` varies every time as I include this file in different scripts which have different paths.

All I am trying to acheive here is : have a file that has all of my code with a `require(vendor/autoload.php)`. And everytime I need to send a email in a different script, I just want to include the file that has `require(vendor/autoload.php)` without having the PATH everytime.

Is that possible and how can I do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide something like a MWE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you are trying to achive and in which part of the code you do not know how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`__DIR__` magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) to make path to `vendor/autoload.php` absolute. For example:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

In this way it will always point to the same file regrades of place where you include/run this file.